# Assembly 8086: Summing 2 registers with MOV and LEA only

Tags: assembly, x86-16, mov

My task is to sum AX and BX to AX, without using "MOV" or "LEA" operands.
I am bit stuck here, can you help me please?

```
; AX need to be 15, using ONLY 'mov' and 'lea'. 
; Do NOT use arithmetic instrutions (add, inc, mul, etc.)

    mov     ax,10
    mov     bx,4

    lea cx,ax
    lea cx, [cx+bx]
```

What am i doing wrong? sorry for my mistakes, i am a newbie.

Comment: Just use the `add` instruction. That's what it's for. There's no reason not to use it.

Comment: Your question is self-contradictory.  Do you want to add without using mov and lea or only using mov and lea ?

Comment: You should always include the exact error messages you're getting in your question.  Or better, put the error message into a search engine.

Comment: Another potential duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648722/addressing-issue-with-mov-instruction-in-x86/28648811#28648811

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The not so obvious thing about `lea` in 16-bit addressing mode today is that not any register can be used as `src` operand. If I recall correctly, you can only add base pointer (`bp`) or index (`bx`) to source or destination index (`si` or `di`) registers. `dest` operand can be any general-purpose register.

The following are allowed:

```
lea ax, [si + bx]
lea ax, [di + bx]
lea ax, [si + bp]
lea ax, [di + bp]
```

At this point I believe you've already got how to do the task:

```
mov si, ax        ; si = ax
lea ax, [si + bx] ; ax = ax + bx
```

Comment: Usually you'd write it as base + index, not index + base.  But yes, those are the only 4 pairs of registers allowed in 16-bit addressing modes.  See also [available x86 addressing modes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34058400/224132), which has some links to more details for 16-bit stuff, but it's mostly about 32/64-bit stuff.